# how to create dynamic assemblies in c# .net?

Tags: c#, .net

In my application, I want to load some methods during run time. that is, i do not know anything about these methods during compile time. there is a configuration file which includes the data for a given scenario, and the methods should be designed according to the needs of those data. then through that configuration file, these new methods are called.

I imagine that this is possible via .net reflection mechanism, by creating a dynamic assembly which one can define to include all the new methods he needs. then the configuration file will call these methods. i know how to call these new methods from my configuration file. i just want to find the mechanism to define a dynamic assembly that includes all these methods.

hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the System.CodeDom.Compiler and Microsoft.CSharp namespaces.

"methods should be designed according to the needs of those data" - is it defined how you'll design those methods or it is a question?